# NHibernate - map Oracle sequence to non-ID column

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

Assuming a table like this:

| ID | FOO | BAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NUMBER | VARCHAR2 | NUMBER |

And a class like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public virtual long Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Foo {get;set;}
    public virtual long Bar {get;set;}
}
```

How do I map `Bar` to the value of a Sequence? It is always NULL though the rest of the data is inserted.

What I tried based on Googling:

```
public SomeTableMapping
{
    Schema("ABC");
    Table("SomeTable");

    // id sequence generator works fine
    Id(p => p.Id, map =>
      {
         map.Column("ID");
         map.Generator(Generators.Sequence, 
           gMap => gMap.Params(new {sequence = "MyID_SEQ"}));
      });

    Property(p => p.Foo, map => map.Column("FOO");

    // This doesn't work, but also doesn't error
    Property(p => p.Bar, map => map.Formula("SELECT ABC.Other_SEQ.nextval BAR FROM dual"));
}
```

> Update

If I change my mapping code to this it generates a value for `Bar` on my SomeClass instance but it does not get set on the record in the database:

```
Property(p => p.Bar, map =>
    {
        map.Column("BAR");
        map.Formula("ABC.Other_SEQ.nextval");
        map.Generated(PropertyGeneration.Insert);
    }
```

Comment: When should the value for Bar be created? On Insert or every update?

Comment: @Firo only on insert

Answer (score 0):

```
Property(x => x.Bar, m =>
{
    m.Column("BAR");
    m.Generated(NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.PropertyGeneration.Insert);
    m.Column(c => c.Default("ABC.Other_SEQ.nextval"));
});
```

so this works

```
var instance = new SomeClass { Foo =  "foo" };
session.Save(instance);
transaction.Commit();

var generatedValue = instance.Bar; // <- generated Value

session.Clear();
var loadedAgain = session.Get(instance.Id);
Assert.Equal(instance.Bar, loadedAgain.Bar);
```

Comment: It is trying to set `Bar` instead of `BAR` so its throwing ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Comment: And, it does not generate the sequence value, it is 0

Comment: @Crowcoder Added the column name. It does not try to set Bar at all on insert but queries the value after insert. It works in a minimal example for me.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, but I need it to insert the value, not generate it after.

Comment: @Crowcoder what do you mean insert the value? The code as is does `Insert(Foo)`, Db creates the value for BAR so the result is a row with foo and Bar filled. there is no after. How would you do it with sql?

Comment: So what do you mean by `. It does not try to set Bar at all on insert but queries the value after insert.` ? If you saw my update then you know I'm getting a Bar value on my object instance but it does not get set in the database.

Comment: Formula is executed every time the object is loaded, so the Bar value is different everytime.  The Code i postet will generate the value once for each SomeClass object when it is inserted. As the question stands the code I posted is correct.